# Configuring Flume on with multiple HTTP source in a cluster

Tags: apache, http, flume

How can I configure `Apache Flume` to listen to multiple `HTTP sources` in a cluster with multiple flume agents?

My flume agent is configured as follows:

```
agent1.sources.httpSource_1.type   = http
...
agent1.sources.httpSource_1.port   = 8081

agent1.sources.httpSource_2.type   = http
...
agent1.sources.httpSource_2.port   = 8082

agent1.sources.httpSource_3.type   = http
...
agent1.sources.httpSource_3.port   = 8083
```

Let's assume I have 5 servers in my cluster. Which address should I send my REST or POST http message to reach all of my 5 servers?

For example, if I will send an HTTP POST message to `<server_dns_1>:8081` then only `agent1` will process it, if I understand it correctly.
How can I use all of my cluster servers and which address should I send my http requests to?

Answer (score 0):

Cantroid, the way you have configured Flume only one agent (`agent1`) will be run. This agent will internally run 5 listening threads.

Being said that, there is no way a single http POST sends a message to all the 5 listening threads (or 5 agents, if you finnally split your unique agent into 5). Not unless you use some load balancing software or you use some "broadcasting" magic at network level (I'm not an expert on that).

Nevertheless, if the reason for having 5 listening ports is you want to perform 5 different data treatments, then you can create a single agent listening in a single HTTP port and then create 5 different channels where 5 different sinks will be listening. The key point with this architecture is the default channel selector is the replicating one, i.e. a copy of the same event will be put into the 5 channels by the unique listening source.